# Strange php opendir/glob issue

Tags: php, glob, opendir

I have a strange issue with opendir (same problem with glob):

```
$dir = "Y:\\\\foldername\\";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Y:\ is a network folder with authentication.
My webserver name is testweb and this script is called tree.php.
Unfortunately my environment is windows based (php 5.2.5 ISAPI, windows 2003 server).

When I open the script from the same machine where IIS is running (http://testweb/tree.php ) everything works fine but if I connect to the same address from another machine (eg my laptop) I get the following error:

> Warning: opendir().. failed to open dir. No error IN D:\web\tree.php

It seems a permissions issue but why it is working from the "local machine" and not from outside? How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Don't use backslashes for paths in PHP - it'll auto-translate for you on Windows. Just use `//server01/foldername` instead, and save yourself from leaning toothpick syndrome

Answer (score 1):

check your permissions on that directory.. you can do it using the function called [is_readable](http://php.net/is_readable)

Comment: same issue... var_dump(is_readable($path)) returs true if I open the browser from the IIS machine.. but returns false from outside..!!

Comment: you said that "Y:\ is a network folder with authentication".. so should the remote machine authenticate to be able to read?

Comment: No.. It's a share mapped in windows with a specific domain account.. It's strange because from a client point of view it should be transparent.. The browser contacts the webserver and php reads a folder (and windows should open it with the appropriate auth). If I open a browser on the same machine as the webserver or not should be the same.. should.. but it seems not!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error before even when I changed the permission and I logged in as admin the error persisted.

I solved this by giving the absolute path for the function opendir() that is instead of writing "subfolder" I wrote "C:\wamp\www\myproject\subfolder" and this solved my problem !

Thanks